# Industrial PC and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

We have some industrial pc with windows xp and windows 7 that are in production line. 
This pc use only one application and that connect with a central server (MSSQL) and on a windows storage (NAS).
Someone suggests to us to move all the machines inside a Active Directory (WINDOWS SERVER 2016), but Windows XP is now dead and to replace the sw and hw we are speaking about 10k$. 
At the same time, for windows 7, there's the user login issue, we want that the machine is ready only by turn on the power, without complex authentication.

There's a way to speak windows server 2016 with this constraint?

Comment: Why does he suggest to move those devices into an Active Directory domain? I would say it's confusing if some of those industrial pc's are in an AD domain and others are not.

Comment: Because the Nas is very permissive and we want use only a big server to catch all production data. But is an idea !

Comment: I don't get it. What does Active Directory have to do with your NAS or SQL server? The same user accounts everywhere? That won't be the case either way if half your computers run WinXP which cannot be joined into the domain anymore.

Comment: You have complete reason, probably the simplest way is to not do anything or make a simple bridge machine.